# How to get the value of several paragraphs with the class name using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, classname

I want to get the text of the paragraph (`p`) contained in div by clicking on that div using the class name. I tried using `innerText` and `innerHTML` but it returns `undefined` in the console. How can I do it using only Javascript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 3</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const showName = document.getElementsByClassName('showName');
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraphs');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(showName, function(element) {
   element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // How can I do it here?
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: https://codepen.io/shinaBR2/pen/qBbxRgz
Basic code is

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(showName, function(element) {
   element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // How can I do it here?
     const text = element.querySelector('.paragraphs').textContent;
     alert(text);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text inside all the paragraphs having "`paragraphs`" class, this code can also help you:

HTML

```
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="showName">
   <p class="paragraphs">Text 3</p>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const showName = document.getElementsByClassName('showName');
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraphs');

for(i=0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    console.log(paragraphs[i].innerText);
}
```